# How to register domain for 15 years?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, google-search, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have heard that Google trust that website which has long expiry date. that want to know how can I register my domain for a long period.

Comment: 10 years is the maximum initial period permitted by ICANN. You can renew it at any time after the first year however, or for another 10 years when the first ten is nearing expiration. It's not the length of the registration period that Google looks at, it's the length of registration _history_ under the same registrant (aka, "domain age") that some might consider a factor. Only time will help with that - what's much more important is the quality of content, links to your site, and how valuable users find it to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why 15 years? Why not 13 or 17 or 21 or 33? Or 42? Or 100? Or perpetuity?

Anyway, it is impossible to answer your question since it depends on the TLD of your domain name. Each registry is free to set up the rules that govern a domain name cycle.

If you have gTLDs in mind, registries are under contract with ICANN which sets many rules, including a limit here. Have a look at the Base Registry agreement here: https://newgtlds.icann.org/sites/default/files/agreements/agreement-approved-31jul17-en.pdf and its section 2.10:

> Registry Operator shall offer registrars the option to obtain initial domain 
>   name registrations for periods of one (1) to ten (10) years at the discretion of the registrar, 
>   but no greater than ten (10) years.

And further below you have the same rules for renewals plus the fact that a domain name can never be expiring more than 10 years in the future (which could happend if you apply the other rules like you register a domain name for 10 years and then you renew or transfer it that would have added time but the other rule is to cap at 10 years maximum delta between now and the domain name expiration).

Many ccTLDs are following the same rules, so 10 years is often a maximum you will see quoted but it is absolutely not a technical limit.

Other TLDs may impose rules not so  related with dates but with usage, especially in the free domain name market. For example in `.TK` the creation and renewals are from 1 to 12 **months**, and you are forbidden to use it for web parking pages or non-existing pages (see http://www.freenom.com/en/dottk_contentpolicy_version21.pdf)

But there is a "catch".
Everything detailed above relates to registries. But most often (there are exceptions), you do not buy your domain name at registries but at registrars. They are free to have their own rules, and for example they can sell you a service where they will take care to renew the domain for you for some amount of years if you prepay them. So they can go far above the registry limit of 10 years... but if they disappear the money you gave them disappear also and you will have no way to enforce it at the registry level... same if you transfer it elsewhere. Also what will appear in RDDS (Whois + RDAP) or in escrow files will always be the registry expiration date caped at 10 years in the future for example for gTLD and even the expiration date from the registrar will show the same and not the whole amount of years you paid.

Network Solutions for example claim to register domains for 100 years, see https://www.networksolutions.com/domain-name-registration/popup-100-yr-term.jsp
There may be others, but this is not very common.

And to slightly amend @dan comment, someone can also hear that the expiration date of a domain name is taken into account, because one can imagine that a spammer/low quality producer/Google algorithm player will be less likely to register a 10-years domain name than a 1-year one (because of course the costs is higher). But this is all speculation.

Note also that they are various initiatives that track "fresh domain names" to apply to them penalties in various red/black/white/green/multicolour lists of domain name reputations, used by various tools, such as anti-phishing, etc. So in that sense I concur with @dan on the fact that what matters more is since how long the domain exist, not when it will expire.

PS: it is silly to try to reverse engineer the Google algorithm (especially when "hearing" some argument from unknown sources) to find one criteria that would "boost" your ranking. Instead, focus on providing an high quality website with useful content and clear navigation, that will make your visitors happy and drive more traffic.

Comment: Google at one time did feel that domains registered for 10 or other long period was a sign that the domain was less likely to be a spam site. This was somewhat true except that domain speculators had no problem registering a domain for a long period because they were hardly paying anything for the domain name in the first place. Domain speculators are the biggest spammers out there. So the whole notion was abandoned very quickly. It was a real factor poorly conceived like so many others Google has come up with and ran with without thinking it through. Cheers!!

Comment: To be precise, it was and still may remain a domain trust factor though I am sure it is no longer an anti-spam factor.

Comment: @closetnoc I doubt Google ever commented that explicitely, so people are just rumoring one way or another. Except if you have some (Google) source?

Comment: Google included domain registration length as a possible factor in a patent on search ranking.   They say they don't actually use it.  See:  [Does a longer registration length/period for a domain name improve its SEO and search ranking?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61519/does-a-longer-registration-length-period-for-a-domain-name-improve-its-seo-and-s)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the link. but a patent does not say this is what they are using (it can be as well a decoy). Google engineer's answer stays elusive they do not say clearly yes or no, as expected, just not to worry about... He is probably not an official spoke person anyway and the algorithm surely often changes, so I would not draw big conclusions in any direction. This is why  my answer is slightly off topic; I concentrated only on the part that is clear and factual - the registraton policies regarding expiration - not so much its relation with Google results.

Comment: It also always irks me a lot that people have only Google on their mind (as if there are not other search engines...) and take great time/energy/money to "optimize" just for it instead of "just" doing a great job with a great website that would be useful to everyone.

Comment: I'd optimize for other search engines if they had any market share to speak of.

Comment: Chicken and egg problem... And "optimizing" for any specific user is to me the opposite of the idea of the Web as invented by sir Tim Berners Lee.

Comment: Please do not think of the Google algorithms as one monolithic thing, it is not. The domain registration length was/is a domain trust factor though the value of such a metric is small. Separate from that is the anti-spam. I believe it was actually used as a factor for a very short period. Be careful when you read things on the net. Google is intentionally misleading at times, contradicts itself, and outright false at other times. If Matt Cutts says they did not use something, people ran with it forgetting that he is talking about his anti-spam algos.

Comment: To be clear, I had access to some Google internal documents including schema and algos while doing research on this topic specifically. We were researching a domain trust mechanism among other things for Internet security and Google was interested to compare notes. I can say at the time that the registration period was a metric for domain trust. This does not mean that there was much if any effect as a result. It was stored and used in domain trust. When you think about it, it is a valuable metric to retain. It does not guarantee an outcome but does predict an outcome. Good for AI.

Comment: "Google is intentionally misleading at times, contradicts itself, and outright false at other times. " and "Google was interested to compare notes", so no guarantee that what you saw is what they are really doing :-)

Comment: What is with the 10-year max registration period.  I what a domain for a lifetime(with zero maintenance), but none of the domains offer this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if domain expiry is a standalone factor for google rankings. Probably, anyone serious about business is going to register a domain at least for say 3 years or so. And they do good work which eventually gets the SERP reward. Hence, the ranking factor is the "good content" and may not be the "expiry date" after all.

The point I am trying to make is this:

Do not assume a proportionate ranking signal strength for the time duration of registration. If that was the case everyone would be registering for 100 years if possible. Register a domain for a reasonable period and never forget to renew on time.

Comment: "anyone serious about business is going to register a domain at least for say 3 years or so"  -- I see many serious businesses that register one year at a time with an auto-renew setting that automatically charges their business credit card.