# Domain Renewal longer then 10 years

Tags: domains

I have a company that needs a basic website for the lifetime of the company being about 50 years.  Is there a service that does this because I have had domain names lapse for services like this before for non tech savvy companies.

Comment: "I have had domain names lapse for services"  You should use monitoring services.

Comment: See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112766/how-to-register-domain-for-15-years  (15, 50, 42, 100, or one thousand years will yield the same answer)

Comment: What the OP needs is not a monitoring service (although it can help), but an **inventory** of owned domain names + anniversary dates. Relying on renewal reminders is a recipe for disaster. The mails may never arrive because of spam filter or otherwise. Now, a domain that has expired will stop functioning correctly so you should notice that your website and E-mail are down, and you have ample time to take corrective action.

Comment: I've heard of a couple people who try and circumvent the 10year ICANN limit by just loading up your domain registrar account with credit then enabling auto renew and hope for the best. I certainly don't recommend it for a whole ton of reasons but if done correctly the registrar will just take some of your credit ever year till it eventually runs out.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "is it possible to renew for longer than 10 years", the answer is **no** as ICANN enforces a 10 year maximum.

Thanks @Patrick for the clarification in the comments.

Comment: Specifically not possible with gTLDs, as ICANN forces a limit on 10 years.